# Checking collision2D on children and parents

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript

I have a GameObject that has a child in it. Both parent and child have a Collider2D on it.

What I want is to (do something) when the parent collides with anything. Do (another thing) when the child collides.

For example: when the parent object collides destroy it but if the child collided Print("You won")

So how can I do it in 2D and preferably using UnityScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach 2DColliders to both the parent and the child. Attach this same script to both parent and child.

```
function OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D) 
{
    if(transform.parent == null)
      Destroy(gameObject);

    else if(transform.parent != null)
      print("You win");
}
```